# using InnerHtml inside XPath expression

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, innerhtml

I am using Selenium Webdriver. I want to locate an element using XPath and innerHtml. How can I do that? is there something like
      //*[innerHtml()='somevalue']
  Thanks.

Comment: If you know the tag you can do it by **(e.g. div)** `//div[contains(.,'some value')]` or `//div[.='some value']`

Answer (score 0):

according to you query: //*[innerHtml()='somevalue']

try this:

```
WebElement foundElement = null;

for (WebElement element : webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*")))
{
    String innerHTML = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    if(innerHTML.equals("somevalue"))
    {
        foundElement = element;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I 've thought of the same thing. However I don't like the solution because it is not performance wise. //* will return a very large collection of element, then we have to loop through all of them to compare innerHTML, that the reason I want innerHTML inside XPath expression.
I think it is not possible, because I will need to make the sample html to be safe inside XPath expression, however if I do so then the text is changed and cannot be compared. Thanks anyway

Comment: I thought your xpath //* is just an example and you will enhance it by adding some tag names to narrow the list

Comment: To better answer your question you need to provide an example what you you search and where.
Basicly innerHtml is not a real attribute in xml/html that you can use in xpath  but a property i DOM representation.